# Python Environment Variable Not Working

Tags: python, error-handling, environment-variables, command-prompt

When I type "Python" into the Windows 10 command prompt I get the error "'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." I've tried adding "C:\Python27" to the "Path" environment variable, but it never works. It doesn't work for the as a user variable or a system variable.

Comment: is the python executable in `C:\Python27`?

Comment: Yes, that's the location

Comment: Either you haven't installed Python2.7 correctly or you have entered the environment variable incorrectly.

Comment: I just tried re-installing python, and I've tried the environment variable about 20 times and a few different ways. I did these things correctly. It has worked in the past.

Comment: Have you tried navigating to `C:\Python27` in the command prompt and running it in there, to make sure that it works how you expect?

Comment: It works in that directory, and now it also works in any directory. I don't know what that did, but thanks a million!

Comment: Had you closed the terminal inbetween? Could just be that, it reads path when it initialises.

Comment: I closed and opened it many times.

Answer (score 0):

Python might not be in your PATH.  Check the environment variables and ensure c:\python27 is in the PATH.